# When were eviction laws created?

Tags: virginia

Originally, eviction was handled as a normal civil tort. That means feudal lords killing each other over land or whatever practical outcome.

At some point there was created a formal eviction process with laws, procedure etc. When did this happen?

Just using Virginia as an example most of our laws were made around 1900 to 1950 so I'm guessing the eviction process was created somewhere in that time.

> The legislation of the Colony of Virginia was not even officially published for the first 175 years of its lawmaking history

> the 1910s Virginia faced much the same dilemma it would face in the 1940s: an aging Code of 1887, with no official revi- sion for nearly 30 years and a structure straining under the weight of added legislation

Also, other states like NY lacked even basic process, like an appelate system so I doubt they were getting into petty civil issues before 1850.

London didn't have metropolitan government until 1889. France introduced the concept of tenant rights in 1948.

Comment: Eviction is the act of the owner of the land removing a tenant, even in the case of a homeowner with a mortgage, if they default the actual owner, i.e. the bank, evicts them. Feudal lords seizing land from each other would be governed by whatever rules or traditions surrounded warfare, so it wouldn't be covered by civil law, or it would be in the grant of the monarch. In either case, eviction law wouldn't apply. As for eviction, tenants of the local lord could be kicked out on the lord's say-so with no recourse.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins, I agree with most of your comment, but the rights and duties of villagers and feudal lords were *mutual*. The lord might have had the right of high, middle, and low justice, but only within the traditionally understood scope. Traditions changed, but only slowly.

Comment: Yes, common law evolved slowly over a few centuries to give tenants actual rights. By the time of US independence, sufficient gentrification had occurred to enshrine some formalised practice for evictions in English civil law, which would have been adopted by the former colonies. Although it would still have strongly favoured the landlord. Looking at the Wiki article on [Eviction in the USA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eviction_in_the_United_States) it suggests the first actual law on the matter in the US was the Indian Removal Act in 1830.

Comment: A "normal civil tort" does **not** mean "feudal lords killing each other over land" or over anything. There were legal procedures for disputes over land ownership and possession from a quite early day that involved courts, not armies, although the procedures and substantive laws were different from current ones. Asking when more or less "modern" eviction laws were passes is on-topic, but legals process goes back farther than bad movies might suggest.

Comment: Ownerships of land in the UK were recorded since at least the Doomsday book - killing each other was no longer an option to simply gain land since then.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins The "Eviction in the USA" Wikipedia article isn't remotely comprehensive. Litigation over petty civil matters was much more common in the early U.S. than it is toady. Eviction actions long preceded both metropolitan government in London (in London) and formal Tenant's rights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

England's system of property laws didn't really contain a recognizable analog to a modern short term landlord-tenant relationship [until the late 17th century](https://engagedscholarship.csuohio.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1607&context=clevstlrev), because modern alienable, inheritable, legally protected land ownership really wasn't a well developed concept until then, although institutions somewhere between leases and mortgaged existed early and would have entitled an eviction-like remedy.

In Europe, this would generally have been codified when [the country adopted its first civil code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civil_code#History), in the very late 1700s and in the 1800s.

In the U.S., it would have been no later than the adoption of the one of the first and most influential comprehensive codified set of rules of civil procedure in the U.S., the [Field Code of New York State](https://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/Field+Code+of+New+York#:%7E:text=The%20first%20code%20of%20Civil,enacted%20by%20the%20state%20legislature.) (named after its principal author, David Dudley Field), in 1848. But piecemeal statutes or ordinances or rules to this effect are much older, probably dating back to at least the early modern period in Europe (i.e. 16th century and later), and in the Colonial era in parts of the Americas including what would become the United States.

For the most part, this would have coincided with the abolition or declining importance of feudalism, and the disappearance of a class of serfs. [Britannica asserts](https://www.britannica.com/topic/history-of-Europe/Landlords-and-peasants) that this transition started to take place in Europe the 16th century. This kind of piecemeal legislation is almost as old as the oldest leases in places that had either literate regularized courts or legislative bodies.

In what is now New York State, [during the Colonial era](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_Law_in_Colonial_New_York), the transition from manorialism and a system of tenancy at will maintained by self-help actions of the landlord, to more modern property right creating lease arrangements started in the 17th century and had fully come to fruition around the time of the American revolution. This thrived in an environment in which a flood of petty litigation in county courts was commonplace and handled matters of general governance as well as litigation of disputes. Litigation over possession of land in organized rule governed civil litigation was common in the late 17th century and 18th century in Colonial America according to Lawrence M. Friedman, "A History of American Law" (1985).

There were legislative provisions like this earlier in more urbanized areas in the Iron Age, [such as the Roman Empire](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2438228), that were abrogated when civilization collapsed in areas where the Roman Empire fell, and with it, rule of law and state entities that were anything other than the personal property of a monarch.

> Originally, eviction was handled as a normal civil tort. That means
> feudal lords killing each other over land or whatever practical
> outcome.

This is not what a civil tort is, let alone "normal" civil tort law. There were trials by combat to resolve some kinds property ownership disputes between lords and also non-aristocratic private land owners in medieval England (there is a whole economics literature about that era, see, e.g., [here](https://academic.oup.com/jla/article/3/1/341/857953)), but there is no sense in which this could be fairly characterized as "tort law".

> Just using Virginia as an example most of our laws were made around
> 1900 to 1950 so I'm guessing the eviction process was created
> somewhere in that time.

This is almost surely incorrect. Most likely, Virginia recodified its laws at this time, but Virginia had plenty of laws on the books and procedural rules [in the Colonial era](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2947233?seq=1) (see also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Court_of_Virginia_(colonial))) before it was even a part of the United States of America.

Eviction law far predates the formation of organized police forces or municipal governments, or any governmentally recognized "tenant's rights" beyond possession if the landlord was paid.

Comment: The Doomsday book, 1086, is the oldest list of land owners I could find (though made for tax reasons).

Comment: @Trish Property ownership is much older than anything resembling a modern lease.

Comment: I know, even found [this](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2438228) & [this](https://www.law.ox.ac.uk/sites/files/oxlaw/ouulj_2nd_edition.pdf)- ROMAN eviction law seems to have existed.

Comment: @Trish revised answer to reflect your link

Comment: Just that Roman Law is antiquity. The Iron age ended around 700 BC in Italy, Rome was founded allegedly 752 BC. the 12 table laws were dated 450 BC - antiquity but not iron age.

Comment: @Trish The term "Iron Age" is often used in a broader sense to refer to everything between Bronze Age Collapse (ca. 1200 BCE) and the beginning of the Medieval era (often dated as beginning with the fall of Rome), including the classical era and "antiquity".

Comment: as a historian, that is the most wrong use of iron age I know. Thohgh, Table 7 of the 12-table roman laws was all [Land Rights & Crimes, so property law.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelve_Tables#Table_VII:_Land_Rights_and_Crimes)

Comment: @Trish Anthropologists are less picky than historians, I guess.

Comment: It's impossible for evictions to start in the 17th century because there were no police.

Comment: @NBolsehv Eviction actions and orders long predate organized police forces. It was a court authorization to remove someone from the premises without liability, that once authorized could be carried out by strong hands, or supervised by court officials.